# strange behaviour by cloning an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a small sample angular app, where I'm experimenting with the kendo UI drawer component. My question isn't related to the drawer itself, but it has a general nature.

I have an `items` array of objects, based on which the drawer is populated:

```
export const items = [
  {
    text: 'France',
    icon: 'user',
    selected: false,
    expanded: false,
    parent: true,
    level: 0,
    id: '0',
    children: [
      {
        text: 'Paris',
        level: 1,
        id: '0.1',
      },
      {
        text: 'Lyon',
        selected: false,
        expanded: false,
        parent: true,
        level: 1,
        id: '0.2',
        children: [
          {
            text: 'Lyon 1',
            level: 2,
            id: '0.2.1',
          },
          {
            text: 'Lyon 2',
            level: 2,
            id: '0.2.2',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    text: 'Italy',
    icon: 'gear',
    expanded: false,
    selected: false,
    parent: true,
    level: 0,
    id: '1',
    children: [
      {
        text: 'Rome',
        level: 1,
        id: '1.1',
      },
      {
        text: 'Milan',
        level: 1,
        id: '1.2',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Now, on component loading or if the user selects the first time an item, I do a clone of this array with this function:

```
public resetItems(): Array<any> {
    const arr = [];
    items.forEach((item) => {
      arr.push(Object.assign({}, item));
    });
    return arr;
  }
```

And then I assign the returned array to a temporary array like this:

```
if (this.newItems.length === 0) {
      this.newItems = this.resetItems();
    }
```

The user can select, expand, collapse an item. By clicking on an item, I set the appr—property accordingly (selected, expanded).

In the above example data, I have a parent France and two children (Paris, Lyon), where Lyon has another two children too (for test purposes). Now, if I click on France and expand the drawer, in the `items` array, on the France object, the properties `selected` and `expanded` remains false. And this is as expected, because I do all this modification on the `newItems` array and not on the `items` itself.

But if I expand Lyon, then the properties `selected` and `expanded` on Lyon are set to true in the `items` array, which shouldn't happen. Why is this? Somehow it seems to me that the `newItems` and `items` array are connected. But they shouldn't.

I wrote two little functions too in order to set `selected` and `expanded` on `newItems` for all items to false and if I set this properties to false like this:

```
this.clearSelection(this.newItems);
this.clearExpandedState(this.newItems);
```

Then only in this case I will have an `items` array, where Lyon isn't selected nor expanded.

Below is all the component code to analyze this.

```
export class AppComponent {
  public drawerExpanded = false;
  public item: any = {};
  public drawerItems = this.resetItems();
  private newItems: any[] = [];

  @ViewChild('drawer') drawer: DrawerComponent;

  public onSelect(e: DrawerSelectEvent): void {
    this.item = e.item;
    const text = e.item.text;

    // if item is no parent, then no action
    if (!this.item.parent) {
      return;
    }

    // if the drawer is collapsed and we click on one of the icons, we expand it
    if (!this.drawerExpanded) {
      this.drawer.toggle();
    }

    // we take a fresh start and reset the items to their original state,
    // but only if we click the first time on any item
    // in other cases 'newItems' must be not overridden
    if (this.newItems.length === 0) {
      this.newItems = this.resetItems();
    }

    // we set the 'selected' property on the clicked item to true (only parents should have the 'selected' property)
    // but before do it, we clear all selection
    // it has the effect, that the parent items have the '.k-state-selected' class too (background color set to primary)
    const index = this.newItems.findIndex((i) => i.text === text);
    this.clearSelection(this.newItems);
    this.newItems[index].selected = true;

    // we expand the clicked item - if not expanded - and add the children into the 'newItems' array
    // else we remove the unnecessary items based on the 'id' field and set 'expanded' to false
    if (!this.item.expanded) {
      this.newItems[index].expanded = true;
      this.addChildren(this.newItems, index, this.newItems[index].children);
    } else {
      this.newItems = this.removeChildren(this.item.id, this.newItems);
      this.newItems[index].expanded = false;
    }

    // refresh the items in the component
    this.drawerItems = this.newItems;

    console.log(items);
  }

  public addChildren(arr, index: number, children: Array<any>) {
    arr.splice(index + 1, 0, ...children);
  }

  public removeChildren(id: string, arr): Array<any> {
    return arr.filter((item) => !item.id.startsWith(`${id}.`));
  }

  public clearSelection(arr) {
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.selected) {
        item.selected = false;
      }
    });
  }

  public clearExpandedState(arr) {
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.expanded) {
        item.expanded = false;
      }
    });
  }

  public resetItems(): Array<any> {
    const arr = [];
    items.forEach((item) => {
      arr.push(Object.assign({}, item));
    });
    return arr;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.clearSelection(this.newItems);
    this.clearExpandedState(this.newItems);
    this.newItems = [];
    this.drawerItems = this.resetItems();
    this.drawer.toggle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you are creating a new array, you are only cloning the very top level of the objects to make new objects-- all the nested items are retaining the reference:

```js
const items = [{ item: { name: 'apple' } }, { item: { name: 'bananas' } }];
const arr = [];
items.forEach((item) => {
  arr.push(Object.assign({}, item));
});

console.log(arr[0] === items[0]); // true 
console.log(arr[0].item === items[0].item) // false

items[0].item.name = 'hello';

console.log(arr[0].item); // { name: 'hello' }
```

To get a *completely* new object devoid of any shared references, you could use a [deep-cloning utility like `lodash`'s `cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep), use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObj))`, or spin your own recursive, deep-cloning utility.

Comment: Believe or not, after asking the question, I went to eat dinner in the kitchen and while warming it, it just ran through my mind, that I do only a simple cloning and not deep cloning. I will accept the answer of course.